# Riemann left sum

Tags: java, math

Trying to figure out how to implement the left sum. Been working on this for hours and have no idea, please help. I get `0.0` from the left sum. The `middleSum` is ok and i use it to check if the `leftSum` works. But it doesnt.***EDIT** the leftSum method is not true, I am still figuring it out ,it would be nice if someone would help and explain how to do the leftSum

```
public static double middleSum(Function fct, double a, double b, int n) {
    double deltaX = (b - a) / n;
    double x = a + deltaX / 2.0;
    double sum = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum = sum + fct.f(x);
        x = x + deltaX;
    }

    return sum * deltaX;
}

public static double lefSum(Function fct, double a, double b, int n) {
    double deltaX = (b - a) / n;
    double x=0.0;
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x=(i-1)/n;

        sum += fct.f(x) * deltaX;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Without any details of what arguments you're passing in there (particularly what `fct` does...) we can't really help you.

Comment: Sorry about that. fct is a function (x*x) a =0 b=2 and n is the number of rectangles which is 100

Answer (score 2):

> I get 0.0 from the left sum

I guess it's because of here:

```
x=(i-1)/n;
```

You're performing integer division here. Change one side as double to perform floating point calculations.

```
x=(i-1.0)/n;
```

Comment: Ok.. but i get 0.6371000000000003 when middleSum gives a result of 2.666600000000003

Comment: @FancyPants Then it's another problem now... certainly with your logic :)

Comment: You probably actually mean: x=a+i*deltax/n

Comment: @hivert get a result of 0.013133999999999998

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why your left code looks do different from the right one. Si for the right you wrote:

```
double x = a + deltaX / 2.0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   sum = sum + fct.f(x);
   x = x + deltaX;
}
return sum * deltaX;
```

Why didn't you write

```
public static double lefSum(Function fct, double a, double b, int n)
{
   double deltaX = (b - a) / n;
   double x=a + deltaX / 2.0;
   double sum = 0.0;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      sum = sum + fct.f(x);
      x = x + deltaX;
   }
   return sum*deltaX;
}
```

for the left sum ?
It's the same code by I start with `x=a` instead of a shifted.

The code writen here returns:

```
Java Main2Integrate 
2.666600000000003
2.666600000000003
```

On my machine.

Comment: I got the first one from my teacher so I didn't edited it and left it as it is.

Comment: So the second one is very similar bu the `x` are shifted by `-deltax/2.0`. And if you want right sum start with `x=a + deltaX`. Draw a picture and it should becomes clear.

Comment: Isn't the left one x-i?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to add `x` which is a length on your picture with `i` which is just a counter. The i-th interval is `[a+i*deltax, a+(i+1)*deltax]`.

Comment: x = a+(i+1)*deltaX; give me a 135.34 result and a+i*deltax gives 131.34

Comment: Sorry can you post somewhere (http://pastebin.com/) the full code or try what I wrote below.

Comment: @FancyPants : Is this a joke ? Where is the code for F1 ?

Comment: @FancyPants: You forgot `return sum*deltaX`;

Comment: now i get the middle 2.666600000000003 and the left 2.6268000000000002
they're extremely close but they should be almost identical***EDIT* They're ok thank a alot

Comment: I'm done with you ! The code I posted here works for me. You don't even try to understand.

Comment: What do you mean not eve try to understand, do you even try to explain? i spent hours trying to do this by my self before I came here. Don't think that I just sat for 5minutes, thought"Aaaghh.. I don't know how to do it ,so I'll just post it on stackoverflow and some guy will help me" I tried to do it by my self and it didn't work, so don't you dare say that I didn't try to understand it. By the way, you are more then welcome to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Left Riemann Sum

For the left Riemann sum, approximating the function by its value at the left-end point gives multiple rectangles with base Δx and height f(a + iΔx). Doing this for i = 0, 1, ..., n − 1, and adding up the resulting areas gives

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Left_Riemann_Sum

```
public static double lefSum(Function fct, double a, double b, int n)
{
   double deltaX = (b - a) / n;
   double x=0.0;
  double sum = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {


     x = a + i * deltaX;

     sum += fct.f(x) * deltaX;

  }

  return sum;
}
```

Comment: get 131.34 as a result. middleSum gives 2.666600000000003

Comment: @FancyPants : Not with the code writen Here. Please pay attention, not mixing two suggested solution !

Comment: @hivert Sorry, just started second semester java. Thanks again!